# How to get the material "500" of any color?

Tags: android, material-design

I have a color in mind for my app. For following the material design guidelines, I need to get the 500, 700, 300 and accent color of that color. Is this possible? Or do we get those only for the colors shown [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette)?

Comment: You will need to use your knowledge about **values** folder.

Comment: As @Selvin said, 500 is just a code given to a colour. The hex value is given at the right, for instance `#f44336`.

Comment: Are you looking for algorithm to give you 500, 700.. and other colors based on some custom color you provide?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Yes that would be great!

Comment: AFAIK, there is no built in way to get those colors. Most likely Google did not use any fixed algorithm to define basic palettes. This is slightly different question, but it might give you some ideas what to do next http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503998/how-to-create-custom-palette-with-custom-color-for-material-design-app

Answer (score 0):

You will haveto find thecolor code of the colors you wish to use as primary(500) and the rest. Gogle has provided it for the colors it thinks are right. You a different color, you create it yourself.

[image: Like this]

Comment: So after selecting the base color, I will have to just use a darker version as 700?

Comment: Exactly. That is what it means to increase the number from 500 to 700. You must have observed a similar pattern while choosing Google fonts.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was a standard for these conversions :(

Comment: The standard does exist, if only you were to ue the colors specified by Google. And to be honest, you will find more of those colors, rather than userCreated colors.